# Select substring until first integer in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
code             number
XY1 N2           2
A2 O1            3
KB11 2HG         2
XY2 J2           3
A1 X2            5
```

I need to select the substring from code until the first integer, i.e. XY1 N2 -> XY, and then aggregate and sum the numbers for these entries, i.e. for XY 2+3, and for A 5+3.

I tried

```
SELECT LEFT(code,position('(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)' in code)-1) FROM listing;
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This query looks like it will do what you need:

```
SELECT 
substring(code, 1, strpos(code, substring(code FROM '(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)'))-1)AS sub1,
sum(number)
       FROM listing
       group by substring(code, 1, strpos(code, substring(code FROM '(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)'))-1)

       ;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3fc75/1

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer you are looking for:

```
select left(code, (select min(position(g::char in code))-1 
                   from generate_series(0,9) g 
                   where position(g::char in code)>0)) as key, sum(number) 
from listing group by key;
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

By help of regular expression match the below simple query will provide desired result.

```
  select
    substring(code,'\D+') as c,
    sum(number)
  from listing
  group by c
```